# How to get Text Selection in WordPress Editor

Tags: editor, visual-editor, post-editor

I want something like if I select any word in WordPress Visual Editor, it will get replaced with my own text.

Actually Visual Editor is an iFrame. We can do this thing in textarea, but how can we implement this in iFrame (WordPress Visual Editor)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to select the word - as an end-user with the mouse? Where does the replacement text come from (local machine clipboard, database, code)?

Comment: Can you post the script that you use for textareas so we can modify it to work with the visual editor?

Comment: I don't understand the upvotes on this one. This question is impossible to understand, the OP doesn't follow up with any sort of details, etc. Close vote as we haven't had an update in the last 14 days, so I see a lack of interest in this one.

Comment: agreed, plus, it's a TinyMCE/JS question not a WordPress question

Comment: @kaiser Re: upvotes - looks like we have our fair share of robo-reviewers.

Answer (score 4):

The visual editor is an TinyMCE implementation. The first way to repace a selected text, is to write a plugin for the TinyMCE.

If you do not want to write a plugin, use the `tinyMCE` object:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'tinyNagging' );

function tinyNagging() {

echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(
function() {
  window.setInterval(
    function(){
      var selectedText = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent( {format : "text"} );
      if ( selectedText != "" )
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent( "FooBar" );
    },
    1000
  );
}
);
</script>
';

}
```

This script checks every second if a text is selected and replace it with 'FooBar'.

Get the selected text with `tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent( {format : 'text'} );` for plain text or `{format : 'html'}` for the html markup.

Set the new content with `tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent( [YourNewContent] );`

See the [TinyMCE manpages](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aclass.tinymce.dom.Selection)